# Movement value is reset before it can get cancelled by a UnityEvent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, game-physics

I've been using Unity for a few days and I'm trying to create a simple plateformer. I'm currently doing the basic player character physics, but I'm trying to use the "new" InputSystem and my character movement only happens for 1 frame each press instead of being able to hold it down.

I tried a few things like adding conditions that check the Callback on its sarted and performed states, I have identified that the issue is that the function itself instantly resets the values because it goes and gets the ReadValue 1 too many times or at least it seems that way.

[image: The input function]

[image: The console prints]

I've been struggling with it for a while and I can't find a solution because the events that the InputSystem uses seem to be called at times that I can't control without completely side stepping the UnityEvents and going with my own, which is a pain and the point of this little project is to learn to use the UnityEvents and InputSystem better.
I've also made sure that I am not stupidly resetting movement.x anywhere else in the code multiple times.

[image: Other useful parts of code]

The more I try things out the more it seems that the issue is that the ReadValue().x is applied to movement.x one too many times when itself is set at 0 before the event gets cancelled, and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO, please dont post pictures of code, please post code in code tags.

Comment: looking at this your debug points arent clear so the output isnt clear, but the output here looks normal, so if its not what you expected..  then perhaps explaining what you expected, as your code (and doesnt cache) the value of the movement vector, prints movement.x which would be 0 cos you hadnt set it, then reads it into movement, so now x is 1, you then check if its < 0 and set player states, you then see if its > 0 and set player states  which frankly could be just done if !=0,  print x again still 1, there is no proof here that the last 0 even comes from that code chunk..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void InputHorizontal(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {
  if (context.started)
  {
    if (context.ReadValue<Vector2>().x != 0)
    {
      playerStates |= States.Walking;
      if (context.ReadValue<Vector2>().x < 0f)
      {
        playerStates &= ~States.FacingRight;
        playerStates |= States.FacingLeft;
      }
      if (context.ReadValue<Vector2>().x > 0f)
      {
        playerStates &= ~States.FacingLeft;
        playerStates |= States.FacingRight;
      }
    }
  }
  if (context.canceled)
  {
    playerStates &= ~States.Walking;
  }
}

void AddMovement() {
  if (playerStates.HasFlag(States.Walking) || speed > 0)
  {
    if (playerStates.HasFlag(States.FacingRight))
    {
      movement.x = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      movement.x = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

I fixed it by side stepping the issue.

Now the movement doesn't actually directly depends on the `context.ReadValue` and it works. Which does confirm that the `InputSystem` does call the function one too many times through the started and performed events.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. If you'd like to add more information relating to the question, edit the original post to provide any extra information.